# ReSharper seems to ignore external annotation on Debug.Assert(Boolean)

Tags: resharper, nullreferenceexception

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper 8.2.1 with extension ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations 8.2.1001. Despite of the assertion in the following code, ReSharper warns about a possible `System.NullReferenceException`. It even suggests adding an assertion as a fix.

```
static int Foo(string s)
{
    Debug.Assert(s != null);
    return s.Length; // Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
}
```

I have unzipped `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\packages\ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations.8.2.1000.4556.nupkg` and found the expected external annotation that should tell ReSharper to "understand" the assertion.

What could be wrong here?

Edit: It is a debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling a `Release` build, I believe R# will ignore the conditional call to `Debug.Assert`.

Comment: Have you checked in R#'s external annotations config pane? Make sure the DLL you are using is listed correctly there.

Comment: What happens if you replace the assertion with `if (s == null) return;`? Does it still warn about `s.Length`?

Comment: D'oh! Drew, your first comment is the right answer to my problem. Thanks! I misinterpreted that config pane: I thought it refers to the code analysis annotations (NotNull etc.) only, and since mine are somewhere else than in the JetBrains.Annotations namespace, I disabled it.

I will mark your answer as the correct one, though it is actually the comment, so maybe you should edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, I noticed that if you uninstall ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations you are going to have to unlink the previously created ..\Properties\Annotations.cs file from your project.